# Iterating through a list is very slow, how to improve the performance

Tags: c#

I have a method that iterate through a list and display the result of each type one followed by another meaning that I will display result from rd followed by result from cv followed by adz. But the actual method is very slow and it takes long time to retrieve back the results. what are the ways to improve the performance and will it matter using different data structure

```
    private List<AllJobModel> GetAllJobModelsOrder(List<AllJobModel> result)
    {
        var countItems = result.Count;
        List<AllJobModel> list = new List<AllJobModel>();
        while (countItems != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < countItems; i++)
            {
                if (result.ElementAt(i).JobImage.Contains("rd"))
                {
                    list.Add(result.ElementAt(i));
                    result.RemoveAt(i);
                    countItems--;
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < countItems; i++)
            {
                if (result.ElementAt(i).JobImage.Contains("cv"))
                {
                    list.Add(result.ElementAt(i));
                    result.RemoveAt(i);
                    countItems--;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < countItems; i++)
            {
                if (result.ElementAt(i).JobImage.Contains("adz"))
                {
                    list.Add(result.ElementAt(i));
                    result.RemoveAt(i);
                    countItems--;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(int i =0; i < countItems; i++)
            {
                if((!result.ElementAt(i).JobImage.StartsWith("rd") && !result.ElementAt(i).JobImage.StartsWith("adz")) && !result.ElementAt(i).JobImage.StartsWith("cv"))
                {
                    list.Add(result.ElementAt(i));
                    result.RemoveAt(i);
                    countItems--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }    
       return list;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried before? what have you researched? what did you google already?

Comment: I have found out the using dictionary data structure is much better

Comment: however, the principle will remain the same in my point of view for loop is needed any all cases but what I might dont know about is that there would be a functions or an algorithm that can be used to faster processes the search for the items within the list

Comment: You are iterating over the list 4 times while you can do a single pass. How many items are there in the list? The `string.Contains` operation, as other string operations in .net, is optimized to its max, so you should look to minimize your cpu cycles. You have 4xN right now (or less, ok), and can change it to N as the answer with LinQ suggests below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bad way to sort. You're effectively looping over the list 4 times, extracting specific groups of items each time. You also have a potential bug by removing items as you are iterating over the list. While there are many improvements you can make to your method, a better way would be to use `OrderBy` with the following sort condition:

```
list = result.OrderBy( m => m.JobImage.Contains("rd")  ? 1 : 
                            m.JobImage.Contains("cv")  ? 2 :
                            m.JobImage.Contains("adz") ? 3 : 
                            4)
             .ToList();
```

Comment: can you explain the process of the linq query

Comment: What do you mean by "the process"? `OrderBy` returns an iterator that gives you the items in the order you specify. Do you mean how the ordering actually works or how the expression (ternary operators) dictate the order of the items? For the former, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: what do you mean by ? 1 :

Comment: will this code return the result from each type one followed by the another

Comment: Read the docs on [? operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator). Essentially `x = A ? B : C` means `x = if A then B else C`. When you chain them this way you get `x = If a then 1 else if b then 2 else if c then 3 else 4`. If you then sort by that value (1-4) then you get the desired sort order.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: https://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-collection-for-string-lookups

Was very helpfull for me.

Regarding your specific problem. It looks like you're doing some filtering of the data. Linq has an easy way of doing that. I haven't test performance but if you can give me some example data ill try it for you. It could be something like this.

```
    private List<AllJobModel> GetAllJobModelsOrder(List<AllJobModel> result)
    {
        return result.Where(x => x.JobImage.Contains("rd") || x.JobImage.Contains("cv") || x.JobImage.Contains("adz")).ToList();
    }
```